# help me reason about F# threads

Tags: multithreading, f#, asynchronous, mono

In goofing around with some F# (via MonoDevelop), I have written a routine which lists files in a directory with one thread:

```
let rec loop (path:string) = 
  Array.append
    (
        path |> Directory.GetFiles
    )
    (
        path 
        |> Directory.GetDirectories
        |> Array.map loop
        |> Array.concat
    )
```

And then an asynchronous version of it:

```
let rec loopPar (path:string) = 
  Array.append
    ( 
        path |> Directory.GetFiles
    )
    ( 
        let paths = path |> Directory.GetDirectories
        if paths <> [||] then
            [| for p in paths -> async { return (loopPar p) } |]
            |> Async.Parallel
            |> Async.RunSynchronously 
            |> Array.concat
        else 
            [||]
    )
```

On small directories, the asynchronous version works fine.  On bigger directories (e.g. many thousands of directories and files), the asynchronous version seems to hang.  What am I missing?

I know that creating thousands of threads is never going to be the most efficient solution -- I only have 8 CPUs -- but I am baffled that for larger directories the asynchronous function just doesn't respond (even after a half hour).  It doesn't visibly fail, though, which baffles me.  Is there a thread pool which is exhausted?

How do these threads actually work?

**Edit:**

According to [this document](http://www.mono-project.com/ThreadPool_DeadLocks):

> Mono >=2.8.x has a new threadpool that is much, much harder to deadlock. If you get a threadpool deadlock chances are that your program is trying to be deadlocked.

:D

Comment: WRT to a deadlock, that is very likely. Consider the case where to finish the dir of folder B you need to add X threads to the thread pool. However, that is blocked until the previous threads have finished; except that they are blocked by needing to spawn more threads in the thread pool...

Comment: For managed stacktraces of a hung program $PID, "kill -QUIT $PID" and check the program's console output. For native stacktraces, "gdb attach $PID" then "t a a bt".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, most likely you are overwhelming the Mono thread pool which is grinding your system's performance to a halt.

If you remember one thing from this, it is that **threads are expensive**. Each thread needs its own stack (megabytes in size) and slice of CPU time (requiring context switching). Because of this, it is rarely a good idea to spin up your own thread for short lived tasks. That is why .NET has a ThreadPool.

A ThreadPool is an existing collection of threads for short tasks, and it is what F# users for its Async workflows. Whenever you do run an F# Async operation, it simply delegates the action to the thread pool.

The problem is, what happens when you spawn thousands of asynchronous actions in F# all at once? A naive implementation would simply spawn as many threads as needed. However, if you need 1,000 threads that means you need 1,000 x 4MB of stack space. Even if you had enough memory for all the stacks, your CPU would constantly be switching between the different threads. (And paging the local stacks in and out of memory.)

IIRC, the Windows .NET implementation was smart enough not to spawn a ton of threads and simply queue the work up until there were some spare threads to perform the actions. In other words, it would keep adding threads until it had a fixed number and just use those. However, I don't know how Mono's thread pool is implemented.

tl;dr: This is working as expected.

Comment: I think you're right: here with Mono, fsi.exe starts up a bunch of threads, but since they're mostly not doing anything, the system isn't stressed at all...

Answer (score 0):

Chris is probably right. The other angle to consider is that filesystems are not fixed things -- are those directories with thousands of files changing as you are trying to process the list? If so, that could be causing a race condition somewhere.

Comment: These are non-system directories with nothing exciting happening like that, but this would be a concern for a real app.  I would guess this is one reason the System.IO.Directory methods return arrays instead of lists: the filesystem is mutable and not controlled by the runtime, anyway.